# Iterating over a dictionary to create a list

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have the following 4 dictionaries in a MongoDB collection called `favoriteColors`:

```
{ "name" : "Johnny", "color" : "green" }
{ "name" : "Steve", "color" : "blue" },
{ "name" : "Ben", "color" : "red" },
{ "name" : "Timmy", "color" : "cyan" }
```

I'm trying to create an ORDERED list of color values matching a different ordered list.

For example, if I have the list `["Johnny", "Steve", "Ben", "Johnny"]` the new list will `["green", "blue", "red", "green"]`.

And if I have the list `["Steve", "Steve", "Ben", "Ben", "Johnny"]` the new list will be `["blue", "blue", "red", "red", "green"]`.

What's a good way of doing this using Python and/or PyMongo. This is what I have so far but it's not recognizing duplicates.

```
name_list = ["Steve", "Steve", "Ben", "Ben", "Johnny"]

color_list = []
for document in db.favoriteColors.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"name": {"$in": name_list }}},
    {"$project": {"color": 1}}
]):
    for k, v in document.iteritems():
        color_list.append(v)

print color_list
# ["blue", "red", "green"]
```

Comment: Can you create a mapping of `'name'` -> `'color'` and then use that mapping  with `name_list` to construct the color_list?  I don't know enough about mongodb to know if this could be done efficiently, but it seems like it could be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we can use the aggregation framework with client side processing to efficiently do this.

```
import pymongo


client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client.test # Or whatever is your database
favoriteColors = db.favoriteColors
first_list = ['Johnny', 'Steve', 'Ben', 'Johnny']

cursor = favoriteColors.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'name': {'$in': first_list}}}, 
    {'$project': {'part': {'$map': {
        'input': first_list, 
        'as': 'inp', 
        'in': {
            '$cond': [
                {'$eq': [ '$$inp', '$name']}, 
                '$color', 
                None
            ]
        }
    }}}},
    {'$group': {'_id': None, 'data': {'$push': '$part'}}}
])
```

Because we [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by None, our cursor contains one document which we can retrieve using `next`. In fact the way we can verify that with `print(list(cursor))`

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(list(cursor))
[{'_id': None,
  'data': [['green', None, None, 'green'],
           [None, 'blue', None, None],
           [None, None, 'red', None]]}]
```

From here, we need to *unpack* the "data" field in the document with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip), chain the inputs using [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and filter out the elements that are `None`.

```
from itertools import chain

result = [item 
          for item in chain.from_iterable(zip(*next(cursor)['data']))
          if item is not None]
```

Which returns:

```
>>> result
['green', 'blue', 'red', 'green']
```

Comment: Can you share the benchmark of your answer with enough queries ?. It seems effecient. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to work but looks so complex. There's gotta be a simpler way to do this using the aggregation framework. Why do you need all those entries under `"$project"`

Comment: @jcmetz21 I don't think that this is complex, I will add explanation and possibly another way to do this if the elements in the output list do not need to appear in this exact order but it is not going to be *simpler*

Comment: The elements need to be in the exact order so this looks good. Thanks!

Comment: @jcmetz21 my answer does not just look good. It is the best way to do this. There may be another way to do this in MongoDB 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

If the datasets are small, you can merge the dicts into a single new dict.

In python3 you can do something like this:

```
names = ["Steve", "Steve", "Ben", "Ben", "Johnny"]
favorites = {d["name"]: d["color"] for d in db.favoriteColors.find()}
colors = [favorites[name] for name in names]
print(colors)
```

## Updated

As styvane mentioned I forgot to call the `find` method on the `Collection`. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Collection object is not iterable. This will miserably fail with a beautiful TypeError

Comment: This is a clean way of doing it if the dictionaries are in python and there's little data to iterate through.

Comment: @jcmetz21 I failed to see how this is *a clean way*. `db.favoriteColors` is a `Collection` object and does not implement the iterator protocol so this query will return a TypeError as I mentioned.

Comment: It works if I throw the dictionaries into a list and iterate over the list. But I do agree this is terrible practice if we're grabbing the dictionaries from MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new `dict` from your current dicts in which every value of `dict["name"]` will be associated with `dict["color"]` value.

For example: the new dict will be like:

```
{"Jhonny": "green", "Steve": "blue"}
```

And you can use a function like the example below which accept many arguments and return the desired list (Also, it appends `None` if there is any name in the input list that is not present in the default dicts):

Here is my example:

```
a = { "name" : "Johnny", "color" : "green" }
b = { "name" : "Steve", "color" : "blue" }
c = { "name" : "Ben", "color" : "red" }
d = { "name" : "Timmy", "color" : "cyan" }

my_list = ["Steve", "Steve", "Ben", "Ben", "Johnny"]

def iter_func(my_list = list, *args):
    ne = {k["name"]:k["color"] for k in args}
    return [ne[k] if k in ne.keys() else None for k in my_list]
```

Output:

```
print(iter_func(my_list, a,b,c,d))
>>> ['blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'green']
```

Example with `None` values:

```
a = { "name" : "Johnny", "color" : "green" }
b = { "name" : "Steve", "color" : "blue" }
c = { "name" : "Ben", "color" : "red" }
d = { "name" : "Timmy", "color" : "cyan" }

my_list = ["Steve", "Steve", "Alex", "Ben", "Ben", "Johnny", "Mark"]

def iter_func(my_list = list, *args):
    ne = {k["name"]:k["color"] for k in args}
    return [ne[k] if k in ne.keys() else None for k in my_list]
```

Output:

```
print(iter_func(my_list, a,b,c,d))
>>> ['blue', 'blue', None, 'red', 'red', 'green', None]
```

Comment: Not the way to do this. What if you have 1  million documents that match your queries?

Comment: The OP didn't say that his queries are huge like you've said. But thanks for your comment. I'll try to improve my answer.